# Can Storing 2 Electromagnetic Speakers Face-to-Face Harm Their Magnets?

Tags: speakers

I have the following 2 speakers:

[image]

They are 11cm in diameter, and have quite big magnets.

In the image, you see them side by side.

If I store them face to face, like this:
[image]
can it harm their magnets?

I ask this, because when 2 speakers are adjacent face to face, their magnets have similar polarity facing one another.
Add to that the fact that they have 0cm distance between them,
it makes me fear that maybe they can weaken each other's magnet..

Can that actually happen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with sound design.

Comment: maybe the name should be "Sound" instead of "Sound Design"..

Comment: Spaceman - the community was formed from a sound design community and an audio community, so sound design is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Loss of magnetism depends on heat, external opposing field, and magnet type. Those are probably ferrite magnets. This should be fine unless they get *really* hot. Its also better than storing them back to back, of course.